# how to solve 'Not Found ' message in expressjs with elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, bigdata

could you inform me how to solve this error message at expressjs

```
POST /test/_search 404 45.691 ms - 1235
Trace: Not Found
```

i've just attempted this code in expressjs with elasticsearch

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
client.search({
  index: 'test',
  body:{
    query:{
      multi_match:{
          query: 'i5',
          fields: ['title']
          }
        }
      }
 }).then(function (response) {
     var hits = response.hits.hits;
     console.log(response);
     console.log(response.hits);
     console.log(response.hits.hits);
  }, function (error) {
      console.trace(error.message);
  })
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express'});
});
```

please help this problem thank you

Comment: What happens when you open the page at the browser?